# What is the proper way to query a Wordpress custom field

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this working query that successfully gets the custom field data in my page template file:

```
<?php $featuredpost_cat = get_field('featured_category_id'); ?>
```

If I echo that out into the page I get "23" the value of the custom field, so I know that is working, what I want to do is grab that value and use it as a query parameter.

Farther down my page I have this:

```
<?php query_posts( $featuredpost_cat . '&posts_per_page=1'); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

All that this does is ignore my variable and return the latest post on the site.

I hope this is clear enough.

== Edit ===

In case I am not being clear, I want to get a custom field which is a category ID from the page, then use it in a query on the page template.

So I set the field as category ID: 23 and then call it in my query_posts function so that I only return posts from that category.

Maybe the full page of code will help: [template code](http://pastebin.com/XhKS8byu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
<?php query_posts( 'cat='.$featuredpost_cat . '&posts_per_page=1'); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

I assume that $featuredpost_cat is a category id

Comment: it is supposed to get a category ID, but your code is not working, or I am implementing something wrong :)

Comment: This does work, I had to eliminate a little user error and typo on my end. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't understand your second code example. Are you trying to use ternary operator to accomplish this?

```
query_posts('cat='.$featuredpost_cat . '&posts_per_page=1');

if (have_posts()){
  while (have_posts()){
    the_post();
  }
}
```

What does `query_posts()` and `the_post()`do? If `query_post()` fetches the posts, `have_post()` checks the existance of posts and `the_post()` echoes them on the page, the code above should work. If this is not the case, please tell what the functions do.

---

Edit. Removed the question mark.

Comment: @Selvaraj If it's the first `$_GET` variable appended to the URL it might be needed. I'm not sure if anything is appended to the URL or is it optional. Can you or gabearnold tell me if it's needed?

Comment: I tried your code and it still performs the same, just returns the same latest blog post.

Comment: @gabearnold Try and write the query out, i.e. don't use any functions in creating the query. You do seem to have posts per page setting active. Try also without it. Or do you have functional (and tested) pagination?